# IRB called from byebug loses context

Tags: ruby, irb, byebug

When I call IRB from a byebug breakpoint I seem not to be in the expected context. Is this a bug or am I doing something incredibly stupid?

```
$ ruby -v
ruby 2.2.0p0 (2014-12-25 revision 49005) [x86_64-darwin14]
$ ruby test.rb 
test

[3, 12] in test.rb
    3: 
    4:  def initialize
    5:      @a = "test"
    6:      puts @a
    7:      byebug
=>  8:      puts @a
    9:  end
   10: end
   11: 
   12: Test.new
(byebug) irb
2.2.0 :001 > @a
 => nil
```

I'd expect @a to be "test", but it's undefined/nil.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't call irb, you can use the byebug prompt in the same way as you'd use IRB.

Comment: It's not completely equivalent (it can't deal with multiple lines of code) but it does solve 80% of situations.

Comment: @MattW. I agree, the multiple lines of code is such an important feature that byebug seems to be missing. I feel stuck when I can't paste new methods or multi-line condition statements. Did you ever figure out a workaround?

Comment: @ndbroadbent: Try pry: ```require 'pry'; binding.pry; / then run it and use $ to show the source.

Comment: @MattW. Thanks, yeah I just switched to using `binding.pry`, and that's much better. Especially with the `c`, `n`, `s`, `f` shortcuts in my `~/.pryrc`.

Answer (score 2):

It is a bug, you should open an issue in Byebug's issue tracker if you want it fixed or at least studied.